# Passing parameter from a URL to a hidden input field

Tags: visualforce, force.com

Is it possible to pass a parameter through a URL to an input field on a Visualforce page? It would be like pre populating a field, but in this case it would be hidden.

Comment: Yes you can with the help of a controller. It acts as other input fields but not visible. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputHidden.htm

Comment: are you trying to avoid initializing fields via a controller and trying to do this with URL hacking? -- and, if you have a controller, with access to the value from `apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fooParm')` - why do you need the hidden field at all?

Answer (score 2):

you can input your parameter via URL like `ap2.salesforce.com/vfPages?id=01Z90000000EkUk` for example

and you can add this 
`Id testId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id')` to get the parameter from url then you can put the `testId` to hidden input field that you want